# problem with fopen and fwrite

Tags: php

hi when i execute this code nothing happen in browser but when i delete lines with star,the contents printed correctly,whats wrong??

/////////////////

```
$documentroot=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$handle=fopen("$documentroot/order/order.txt",'r+');

if(!$handle) {
  echo 'error opening file';
} 

$content="pepsi\ncola\npeperoni";
$write=fwrite($handle,$content); //*

if(!$write){ //*
  echo 'error writing'; //*
} //*

while(!feof($handle)) {
$string=fgets($handle);
echo $string;
}
```

Comment: are you sure the PHP account (eg, www-data) has write access?

Comment: You need to use `($write === false)` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

this line should be like this.

```
$handle=fopen("$documentroot/order/order.txt",'w');
```

file should be open in the write mode.try this.

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is that i dont type rewind($handle),thanks for answering,so much

Answer (score 0):

`/*` This is the opening tag on PHP and it needs to be closed with another `*/` but the `*` in front this time. You can stick with // for just one line of commenting.

Comment: the problem is that i dont type rewind($handle),thanks for answering,so much,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in `r+` mode which means read+write mode. But if the file `orders.txt` does not exist, it'll **not** be created. So ensure file exists.

Also when there is problem with opening the file, you immediately **exit**.

```
if(!$handle) {
  echo 'error opening file';
  exit; // MISSING
}
```

Assuming the file already exists, it's contents will be wiped after the `fopen`. Next the `fwrite` will write the contents. Now the file pointer is at the **end** of the file so your call to `feof()` in the `while` loop will return `true` and the while is never entered.

To fix this you rewind the file pointer before you start reading from the file:

```
rewind($handle); // ADD THIS

while(!feof($handle)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$documentroot=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$handle=fopen("$documentroot/order/order.txt",'r+');

if(!$handle) {
  echo 'error opening file';
} 

$content="pepsi\ncola\npeperoni";
$write=fwrite($handle,$content); 

if(!$write){ 
  echo 'error writing'; 
} 
fseek($handle, 0);
while(!feof($handle)) {
$string=fgets($handle);
echo $string;
}
```

After file write operation, your file pointer sets to the end of written data which needs to set to the start position for fgets. fseek does that.

> fseek($handle, 0);

This will take your pointer to the beginning so that fgets now can read from file. fgets function needs valid file pointer to read which in this case is the start position.